# load an object if a key contains a specific value (month)

Tags: python, json, get, load

Is there a way to load only an object which contains specific key value from json?

The steps what I have done:

```
response = requests.get(URL, headers={'token': TOKEN}, verify=False)
meta_json = json.loads(response.content)
```

meta_json looks like this:

```
{
      "count": 264428,
      "data": [
        {
          "calculation_date": "2020-04-09T12:33:05.814107",
          "name": "Felix",
          "age": 12
        },
        {
          "calculation_date": "2020-03-09T12:33:05.814107",
          "name": "Max",
          "age": 18
        },
        {
          "calculation_date": "2020-04-09T12:33:15.814207",
          "name": "John",
          "age": 25
        }
    ],
      "links": {
        "first": "random",
        "last": "second"
      }
    }
```

But I would like to see only the month April, and meta_json should look like this:

```
{
      "count": 264428,
      "data": [
        {
          "calculation_date": "2020-04-09T12:33:05.814107",
          "name": "Felix",
          "age": 12
        },
        {
          "calculation_date": "2020-04-09T12:33:15.814207",
          "name": "John",
          "age": 25
        }
    ],
      "links": {
        "first": "random",
        "last": "second"
      }
    }
```

How to do this?

Comment: `meta_json = {k: v if k != "data" else [i for i in v if datetime.fromisoformat(i["calculation_date"]).month == 4] for k, v in meta_json.items()}`. Docs: [`fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). Btw, you can use [`response.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Answer (score 1):

You could filter your result after the load, like below:

```
meta_json['data']=[i for i in meta_json['data'] if '-04-' in i.get('calculation_date', '')]
```

Comment: I get a KeyError: 'calculation_date' exactly on that line where this code is

Comment: @Davidoff, replace `i['calculation_date']` with `i.get('calculation_date', '')`